# Attempt to assign property "Tenant_id" on null

Tags: laravel

I am developing my laravel project where I want to have a small house rental system. I want to assign Tenant_id a value of user id, who is clicking a button "rent". However, I am getting the error visible above. Here is how my house table looks:

```php
Schema::create('houses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('Creator_id')->constrained('users');
    $table->foreignId('Tenant_id')->nullable()->constrained('users');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('picture')->nullable();
    $table->string('description');
    $table->integer('price');
    $table->integer('area');
    $table->string('city');
    $table->string('country');
    $table->string('street');
    $table->integer('rooms');
});
```

My web.php file:

```php
Route::group(['prefix'=>'client', 'middleware'=>['isClient','auth','PreventBackHistory']], function(){
    Route::get('dashboard',[ClientController::class,'index'])->name('client.dashboard');
    Route::get('profile',[ClientController::class,'profile'])->name('client.profile');
    Route::get('settings',[ClientController::class,'settings'])->name('client.settings');
    Route::get('profile',[ClientController::class,'profile'])->name('client.profile');
    Route::get('profile/{user}',[ClientController::class,'edit'])->name('client.profile.edit');
    Route::post('profile/{user}/update',[ClientController::class,'update'])->name('client.profile.update');
    Route::post('house/{user}',[HouseController::class,'rent'])->name('house');
});
```

My HouseController:

```
public function rent(Request $request)
{
    $houses = House::all();
    $house = $request->input('Tenant_id');
    $house->Tenant_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $house->save();
}
```

My view file:

```html
@foreach ($users as $user)
    @if ($user->id == Auth::user()->id)
        <form method="post" action="{{route('house', $user)}}">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <button class="button" type="sumbit">Rent</button>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Could you please help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What you did is wrong. Your ```$house``` variable is just getting data from a user input. It is not a database collection and thus cannot have ```$house->Tenant_id```.

Comment: Is ```Creator_id``` same as user id?

Comment: How can I get record from the Database?

Comment: You can get a record from the database with a ```where()``` condition to restrict the record gotten to just that specific user.

Comment: Creator_id is not user_id. I get Creator_id from the users table because I have 3 user roles: Admins, Tenants and  Landlords. Only Admins and Landlords can add houses. Creator_id is value for Admin's and Landlord's created houses.

Comment: I don't really understand how can I get this specific house record from the database

Comment: @Innovin this site does not work like that, you have to add an answer or ask in the comments for more info... no emails, no contact outside stackoverflow for security purposes

Comment: @Innovin you can start an open chat channel and discuss every detail with op. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
public function rent(Request $request)
{
    /** 
     * Correct this to find the house how you should, I do not know enough
     * about the rest of the project to give you this line, however, 
     * you can use the find method to find a record and return a 
     * collection based on the condition.
     */
    $house = House::find('id', '=', 'house_id');
    $house->Tenant_id = auth()->id();
    $house->save();
}
```